# How to have Java kafka consumer skip messages?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I currently have some code like this in my Kafka consumer:

```
KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumerMap.get(topic).get(0);
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    String receivedData = new String(it.next().message());
    // do some processing
}
```

Which works really well, receiving every message. Now I want to skip over some messages, because e.g. I just want a sample of the messages. I don't want to have to receive them because I don't want to waste bandwidth. So e.g. I want something like below:

```
KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumerMap.get(topic).get(0);
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    if(sample){
        String receivedData = new String(it.next().message());
        // do some processing
    } else {
        it.skip(); // does not use bandwidth to receive message
    }
}
```

In this case `it.skip()` should simply skip the message, not taking up bandwidth to actually transfer it over the network. I believe the answer has something to do with advancing offsets but I can't seem to find any specific functions that do this.

Comment: If you are really concerned about performance, it's important to remember about message sets. Kafka usually reads and delivers batches of messages at once, not one at a time. There are configuration parameters for the batch sizes. But the point is -- the system is built to deliver a stream of messages. So while you can skip around and save a little bandwidth, you are going to be using the system in a sub-optimal way if you try to read a message here and a message there.

Comment: Thanks David. The bandwidth saving may well be considerable. And the client may not have enough bandwidth to consume at the same rate as being produced. So what's the accepted practice here?

Comment: You can "seek" to skip messages.